# Does jQuery's .click() method work on Bootstrap Star Rating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask if it's possible to enable a submit button after a mouse click on a star rating control.

I have this mark up

```
    <div class="rating-container rating-md rating-animate">
    <div class="rating" id="ratingg">
    <span class="empty-stars">
    <span class="filled-stars">
    <span class="star"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="caption"><span class="label label-default">Great!</span></div>
    <input id="rating" name="rating" class="rating" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="1">
    </div>
<button class="btn btn-file" id="okbtn" type="submit">Continue</button>
```

and jQuery as follow

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#okbtn').attr('disabled','disabled');
     $('#rating').click(function() {
         $('#okbtn').removeAttr('disabled');               
     });
 });
```

Does anyone know why the above example isn't working with JQuery star rating plugin (http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Thanks for all the input, I really appreciate your time and knowledge! Goldie was right, I just had to include the following code in my main.js file:

```
 $(function(){
   $('#ratingg').on("click", function () {
      $('#okbtn').removeAttr('disabled');        
   });
 });
```

Thanks again!

Comment: You have 2 elements with the same id, that is not valid

Comment: just tried your code and it works, maybe there's an error somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$('#rating').on('rating:change', function(event, value, caption) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(caption);
});
```